# ¿Cuál es mi error en esta sección de código?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Soy nuevo en la programación. Estoy aprendiendo y practicando JavaScript, y en medio de la practica me surgió un error. El problema es que no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal.
La porción de código es la siguiente:

```
    reinciarSmartPhone() {
        if (this.encendido == true) {
            alert("Reiniciando SmartPhone.");
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                !this.encendido; };
            alert("SmartPhone reiniciado.") }
        else {
            alert("El SmartPhone está apagado.")
        }
    }
```

Es para una practica, intenté que la propiedad this.encendido cambie de true a false y nuevamente de false a true, pero al intentar ejecutar el metodo la consola me dice que reiniciarSmartPhone no es una función. Si alguien me podría explicar por que no es una función y que error estoy cometiendo me sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: reinciar != reiniciar.

Answer (score 0):

En javascript delante del nombre de la función debes poner 'function':

```
function reinciarSmartPhone() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para declarar una funcion en javascript debes poner **function seguido del nombre de la función** eje: function myFunction() {}

Te vendría bien mirar [estos apuntes sobre cómo declarar functiones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#definir_funciones).

Por otro lado acostumbrate a formatear bien el código, esto facilita tanto a ti como a compañeros a comprender mejor el código:

Tu código formateado:

```
function reinciarSmartPhone() {
    if (this.encendido == true) {
        alert("Reiniciando SmartPhone.");
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            !this.encendido; 
        };
        alert("SmartPhone reiniciado.")
    }
    else {
        alert("El SmartPhone está apagado.")
    }
}
```

Puedes probar aquí el funcionamiento:

```js
reinciarSmartPhone();
function reinciarSmartPhone() {
    if (this.encendido == true) {
        alert("Reiniciando SmartPhone.");
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            !this.encendido; 
        };
        alert("SmartPhone reiniciado.")
    }
    else {
        alert("El SmartPhone está apagado.")
    }
}
```

Comment: En este caso estaba declarando un método para una clase, de igual manera debo poner function para declararlo?

Comment: Si, siempre los métodos son funciones.